# Upgrading from commons-httpclient to httpclient 4.x.jar facing issues with opensaml latest version

Tags: httpclient, opensaml

In my project, I need to update the dependency apache *commons-httpclient-3.1.jar* to *httpclient-4.5.3.jar* because *commons-httpclient.jar* is going to EOL.

The issue I am facing here is *opensaml-2.6.6.jar* has a dependency of *openws-1.5.6.jar* and *that* has a dependency of the *commons-httpclient-3.1.jar*.

The maven repository says we can update to *httpclient-4.5.3.jar,* but when I use OpenSaml setup I am getting the exception below

```
Error ::
/*
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/httpclient/protocol/ProtocolSocketFactory
  at org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLBootstrap.postProcessBeanFactory(SAMLBootstrap.java:42)
  at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:281)
  at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:176)
  at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:686)
  at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:524)
  at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:444)
  at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:326)
  at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:107)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:5118)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5634)
  at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:899)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:875)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:652)
  at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:1092)
  at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1984)
  at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.httpclient.protocol.ProtocolSocketFactory
  at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1892)
  at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1735)
```

Please let me know what needs to be done.

Answer (score 0):

I think OpenSaml v2 will not be updated with new dependency because the v3 has been released and the old version will not support.  [official v3](https://wiki.shibboleth.net/confluence/display/OS30/Home)

According to the maven, I found that openws-1.5.6.jar is used for SOAP, and v3 version of OpenSaml separate it as [OpenSAML:: SOAP Provider API](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.opensaml/opensaml-soap-api), and [this version (3.3.0) depends on httpclient 4.3.6](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.opensaml/opensaml-soap-api/3.3.0).

So I think maybe you need to think about upgrade OpenSaml V3, which has nearly same function (just minor change for method of bootstrap)